# Working with JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a table called "Weights" that holds a user's weight for a specific day. I can retrieve all relevant data as JSON  with the following line of code in my controller's index action:

```
@weights = Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).to_json
```

The output then looks like:

```
[{"id":72,"user_id":71,"kilograms":94.0,"day":"2016-06-03","created_at":"2016-06-03T06:58:35.139Z","updated_at":"2016-06-03T06:58:35.139Z"},{"id":75,"user_id":71,"kilograms":34.0,"day":"2016-06-02","created_at":"2016-06-03T13:05:49.862Z","updated_at":"2016-06-03T13:05:49.862Z"},{"id":76,"user_id":71,"kilograms":56.0,"day":"2016-05-29","created_at":"2016-06-03T13:06:01.747Z","updated_at":"2016-06-03T13:06:01.747Z"}]
```

However, what I would need is an output that looks like:

```
{2016-06-03 => 94.0, 2016-06-02 => 34.0, 2016-05-29 => 56.0}
```

How can I achieve this? (I just started coding so I'm sorry if this is a really noob question)

Many thanks.

> **UPDATE** My request refers to a chart I want to display using Chartkick. The documentation says:
>
> Times can be a time, a timestamp, or a string (strings are parsed)
>
> ```
> <%= line_chart({20.day.ago => 5, 1368174456 => 4, "2013-05-07 00:00:00 UTC" => 7}) %>
> ```
>
> **My weights_controller.rb index action now**
>
> ```
> def index
>
>     result = {}
>     Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).each do |weight|
>       result[weight.day] = weight.kilograms
>     end
>
>   end
> ```
>
> Thus I need my data in format described above.

Comment: You can create a new serializer if you want your approach to be optional al reusable, or you can override the `as_json` method in your model class if you want the customization occur always.

Comment: Nothing to excuse and it's a good beginners question. Current rails comes shipped with a gem called jsonbuilder, that you can use building views of your ressource. Some prefer ActiveModel::Serialization where you can define json outputs to your ressources, where this gem follows convention over configuration like rails itself. Did you have a look on those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let try this:

```
@result = {}
Weight.where(:user_id => current_user.id).each do |weight|
  result[weight.day] = weight.kilograms
end
```

Now the result will be a hash:

```
{'2016-06-03' => 94.0, '2016-06-02' => 34.0, '2016-05-29' => 56.0}
```

If you want result to be json:

```
@result.to_json
```

**Update** Simply use it in the view for example:

```
<% @result.each do |day, kg| %>
  <p>Day: <%= day %>, Kg: <%= kg %><p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why not do a grouped query and jsonify the result?

Comment: Won't the keys look like `2016-06-03T06:58:35.139Z` and not `2016-06-03`?

Comment: Where exactly do I put these lines? In my index action?

Comment: @Oliver Just put it in where you want to use, in controller is just fine

Comment: @AaronBrager: Correct, the OP can easily complete that I think :)

Comment: @unused: Hmm, could you make an answer for your idea?

Comment: @HieuPham change to day =>  `result[weight.day]`

Comment: see the first example of [rails guides - active record querying, group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) to get an idea

Comment: @HieuPham: You were right. Not too hard to change created_at to day. ;-) However as i put your lines in my index action (and I see the logic) I'm still lost. How can I now use these values in my view? Let's say I just want to show the result there?

Comment: @Oliver Just updated the answer, I'm not sure that is what you need, if not, please update you question with the detail :)

Comment: @HieuPham You are right. I should better explain myself. :-) Please find the update above. (btw just copied your code in my index.html.erb and receive a "undefined local variable or method `result' for #<#<Class:0x007f31a8f00ad8>:0x007f31a8ed8470>" error)

Comment: You view will not understand `result`, just change it to `@result` it will work, check the update out!

Comment: Perfect! It's working! Had to change @result[weight.day] = weight.kilograms as well. Thx a lot!